# Why do the principal component values from Scipy and MATLAB not agree?

Tags: matlab, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, pca

I was training to do some PCA reconstroctions of MNIST on python and compare them to my (old) reconstruction in maltab and I happened to discover that my reconstruction don't agree. After some debugging I decided to print a unique characteristic of the principal components of each one to reveal if they were the same and I discovered to my surprised that they were *not* the same. I printing the sum of all components and I got different numbers. I did the following in matlab:

```
[coeff, ~, ~, ~, ~, mu] = pca(X_train);
U = coeff(:,1:K)
U_fingerprint = sum(U(:)) 
%print 31.0244
```

and in python/scipy:

```
pca = pca.fit(X_train)
U = pca.components_
print 'U_fingerprint', np.sum(U)
# prints 12.814
```

why are the twi PCA's not computing the same value?

---

All my attempts and solving this issue:

The way I discovered this was because when I was reconstructing my MNIST images, the python reconstructions where much much closer to their original images by a lot. I got error of `0.0221556788645` in python while in MATLAB I got errors of size `29.07578`. To figure out where the difference was coming from I decided to finger print the data sets (maybe they were normalized differently). So I got two independent copies the MNIST data set (that were normalized by dividing my 255) and got the finger prints (summing all numbers in data set):

```
print np.sum(x_train) # from keras
print np.sum(X_train)+np.sum(X_cv) # from TensorFlow
6.14628e+06
6146269.1585420668
```

which are (essentially) same (one copy from tensorflow MNIST and the other from Keras MNIST, note MNIST train data set has about 1000 less training set so you need to append the missing ones). To my surprise, my MATLAB data had the same finger print:

```
data_fingerprint = sum(X_train(:))
% prints data_fingerprint = 6.1463e+06
```

meaning the data sets are *exactly* the same. Good, so the normalization data is not the issue.

In my MATLAB script I am actually computing the reconstruction manually as follow:

```
U = coeff(:,1:K)
X_tilde_train = (U * U' * X_train);
train_error_PCA = (1/N_train)*norm( X_tilde_train - X_train ,'fro')^2
%train_error_PCA = 29.0759
```

so I thought that might be the problem because I was using the interface python gave for computing the reconstructions as in:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=k)
pca = pca.fit(X_train)
X_pca = pca.transform(X_train) # M_train x K
#print 'X_pca' , X_pca.shape
X_reconstruct = pca.inverse_transform(X_pca)
print 'tensorflow error: ',(1.0/X_train.shape[0])*LA.norm(X_reconstruct_tf - X_train)
print 'keras error: ',(1.0/x_train.shape[0])*LA.norm(X_reconstruct_keras - x_train)
#tensorflow error:  0.0221556788645
#keras error:  0.0212030354818
```

which results in different error values 0.022 vs 29.07, shocking difference!

Thus, I decided to code that exact reconstruction formula in my python script:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=k)
pca = pca.fit(X_train)
U = pca.components_
print 'U_fingerprint', np.sum(U)
X_my_reconstruct = np.dot(  U.T , np.dot(U, X_train.T) )
print 'U error: ',(1.0/X_train.shape[0])*LA.norm(X_reconstruct_tf - X_train)
# U error:  0.0221556788645
```

to my surprise, it has the same error as my MNIST error computing by using the interface. Thus, concluding that I don't have the misconception of PCA that I thought I had.

All that lead to me to check what the principal components actually where and to my surprise scipy and MATLAB have different fingerprint for their PCA values.

Does anyone know why or whats going on?

---

As warren suggested, the pca components (eigenvectors) might have different sign. After doing a finger print by adding all components in **magnitude** only I discovered they have the same finger print:

```
[coeff, ~, ~, ~, ~, mu] = pca(X_train);
K=12;
U = coeff(:,1:K)
U_fingerprint = sumabs(U(:))
% U_fingerprint = 190.8430
```

and for python:

```
k=12
pca = PCA(n_components=k)
pca = pca.fit(X_train)
print 'U_fingerprint', np.sum(np.absolute(U))
# U_fingerprint 190.843
```

which means the difference must be because of the different sign of the (pca) U vector. Which I find very surprising, I thought that should make a big difference, I didn't even consider it making a big difference. I guess I was wrong?

Comment: How many components do both versions return? Comparing the documentation, that might be a point of difference that might explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: @rubenvb they are both 12 (obviously the same or else it would be silly mistake on my part, I will provide the github code tomorrow morning for the scripts for people to judge).

Comment: In MATLAB variables are column mayor and in python row mayor. MAke sure you are not computing the PCA in the transposed matrix.

Comment: Instead of the MNIST data, could you apply the PCA to a very small array in matlab and python, and simply look at the results to see the difference?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser sure, I'd be happy to test it in a different data set. I thought it would be easier for people to have the same data set as I am using by referencing a standard data set. How would a different data set make it easier to help? (Im genuinely curious)

Comment: With a *small* data set, you could simply print `U` and compare the output in matlab and python, instead of comparing the "fingerprint" (i.e. the sums of `U`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the problem, but it certainly could be.  Principal component vectors are like eigenvectors: if you multiply the vector by -1, it is still a valid PCA vector.  Some of the vectors computed by matlab might have a different sign than those computed in python.  That will result in very different sums.

For example, the matlab documentation has this example:

```
 coeff = pca(ingredients)

 coeff =

   -0.0678   -0.6460    0.5673    0.5062
   -0.6785   -0.0200   -0.5440    0.4933
    0.0290    0.7553    0.4036    0.5156
    0.7309   -0.1085   -0.4684    0.4844
```

I have my own python PCA code, and with the same input as in matlab, it produces this coefficient array:

```
[[ 0.0678  0.646  -0.5673  0.5062]
 [ 0.6785  0.02    0.544   0.4933]
 [-0.029  -0.7553 -0.4036  0.5156]
 [-0.7309  0.1085  0.4684  0.4844]]
```

So, instead of simply summing the coefficient array, try summing the absolute values of the coefficients.  Alternatively, ensure that all the vectors have the same sign convention before summing.  You could do that by, say, multiplying each column by the sign of the first element in that column (assuming none of them are zero).

Comment: seems like the two principal component matrices (eigen vector) had the same finger print now that I computed the new finger print with absolute value as you suggested. Does that mean that the reconstruction is being computed wrongly because the sign of the eigen vectors disagree?

Comment: The sign should not make a difference because the reconstructions are made via X_reconstruct = U * U.T * X which cancel out the sign.

Comment: if look at my code more carefully one can notice that I was computing the norm 2 loss but then square rooting it (or I guess more precisely not squaring it) in one and the other one was computing the squared error but I squared the error. Which took into account the differences. Thanks for the help though! :D